# Prove $P_S(x)$ divide $P_T(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a vector space of finite dimension and $T:V\rightarrow V$ a linear operator. if $W$ is subset of $V$ such that $T(W)\subset W$ and $S=T|_W$ in other words ($S:W\rightarrow W $ is defined by $S(w)=T(w))$ is the restriction of $T$ to $W$ prove $P_S(x)$ divide $P_T(x)$

I don't have idea of how to prove this exercise. I'm very stuck. Can someone help me with a hint or something?

Thanks for his time!

Comment: What are $P_T(x)$, $P_S(x)$?  The minimal or characteristic polynomials of $T$ and $S$?

Comment: characteristic polynomial @RobertLewis in other words $P_A(x)=det(x\lambda-A)$ where $A$ is a matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a basis $(e_1,...,e_m)$ of $W$ that you complete with a basis of $V$, $(e_1,..,e_m,e_{m+1},..,e_n)$. The matrix of $T$ in this basis as the form:

$M_T=\pmatrix{M_S&A\cr 0&B}$, when you compute $det(xI-M_T)=det\pmatrix{xI_W-M_S&A\cr 0&B'}$ you obtain $P_S.Q$

Comment: Okay, i see, $P_T(x)=P_S(x).Q(x)$ following your answer, $det\pmatrix{xI_W-M_S&A\cr 0&B'}=det(xI_w-Ms)det(B')=P_s(x).det(B')=P_s(x)Q(x)$ no?

Comment: i only can not see why $M_T=\pmatrix{M_S&A\cr 0&B}$ can you explain me that detail? thanks for you time! i'm very glad.

Comment: but the first comment is the answer

Comment: is for the form of your take the basis, no?  you obtain this $M_T=\pmatrix{M_S&A\cr 0&B}$

Comment: yes, it is for that i take that basis

Comment: thanks, excellent answer. thanks for your time! i'm very glad.